# Verify Ownership of Azure App Service Domain

Tags: azure, dns, office365

I have registered a domain name through the Azure portal. I'm currently in the process of trying to verify ownership of it on Office365 so I can register email for it.

However, it looks like Azure uses GoDaddy as their DNS provider. Unfortunately, since I registered through Azure portal I don't have a way to sign into GoDaddy and go through the necessary steps to prove ownership of the domain.

On the Azure side, I attempted to delegate the app service domain to an Azure DNS Zone per the DNS Zone blade for said app service domain. However, when I click the delegate button, I get the following error:

> Failed to update the domain to use Azure DNS: An error has occurred.

No further information. Is there anyway I can actually give proof that I own this domain?

GoDaddy support said they couldn't help me and that I need to call the registrar. However, I don't have a paid support plan with Azure so I can't actually call them.